# can we deploy two applications with same application name and different versions in wso2 esb

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I want to deploy two applications with same name but with different versions.
`sample-capp-1.0.0` and `sample-capp-2.0.0` . It gives me this error while deploying :

Caused by: `org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Duplicate entry definition for key.`

**PS -**  One way is to create multiple tenants in the server. But is there any better way to do that? I am using esb version 5.0